# TFS: Why do Issues appear on the Backlog?

Tags: tfs, project-management, tfs-workitem, azure-devops

We are using TFS 2015 together with the CMMI process template and I have just found out that Issues do appear on the backlog if they are a child of a Feature or a Requirement work item type. If the Issue is standalone (has not link to one of the two mentioned work item types) it is not visible on the backlog.

I guess that someone has made some hacks here in order to make this possible. Originally, only Epics, Features, Requirements, Tasks, and Bugs should appear on the backlog.

I have checked the Issue work item type definition as well as the processconfiguration.xml and the categories.xml which look quite ok from my point of view.

Are there any another places where one could define which work item types should be visible on the backlog?

Thanks a lot for giving support.

Answer (score 0):

To add a WIT on backlog, the three files below need to updated:

- WIT Definition
- Categories Definition
- ProcessConfiguration Definition

You can check the required changes on this link: [Add work item types to backlogs and boards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/work/customize/add-wits-to-backlogs-and-boards#wit-as-requirements) to see if these changes had been applied on your project. If yes, revert these changes, then the Issue should disappear from the backlog.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well... None of those files have changes as written in your link. Even more strange: I have exported those three files from the corrupt project and imported them in a fresh team project. Then, the Issues are not visible on the backlog (below features and requirements) of the fresh team project.

Comment: @Rickson It's really strange. Can you share a screenshot for how the issue displays in backlog?

Comment: Do you have an email address to which I could sent the screenshots? Unfortunately, I cannot post it here.

Comment: @Rickson v-eddche@microsoft.com

Comment: Thanks! I will soon write you an eMail.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the "child" link to associate with Issues.

The Parent/Child link is used for the backlog and I would think that the Issues are appearing because of this.

Try changing the Parent/Child link to Related.

Comment: Well, if I use the child link together with Issues in a fresh TFS team project, the Issues do not appear on the backlog. However, if i do the same in our "corrupted" team project, they do appear on the backlog...

Comment: Then in your Catagories.xml process template section "Issue" has been added to be displayed on the backlog.

Comment: Nope. Nothing regarding Issues has been added to Categories.xml.